# RxJava subscribe multiple observables separately and together

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I have two network requests.

```
fun getPostDetail(postId: Int): Single<Post>
fun getComments(postId: Int): Single<List<Post>>
```

What I want to do is...

1. Show loading screen when it starts. those two requests should work independently.
2. As each request completes, the showing results updated.
3. Hide the loading screen when all the requests terminate.

I have functions that handle the loading page:

```
fun showLoadingScreen()
fun hideLoadingScreen()
```

and manipulate the view:

```
fun showPostDetails(post)
fun showComments(comments)
```

I've tried this way - subscribe each, and also subscribe merged one:

```
postDetail = getPostDetail(postId)
getComments = getComments(postId)

postDetail.subscribe()
getComments.subscribe()

Single.merge(postDetail, getComments).subscribe()
```

In this case, it makes multiple requests rather than once.

What's the best approach to this kind of problem? I can use `CountDownLatch` for counting the completion of each request, but is there any other descent solution to this in RxJava?

Comment: Why not just use merge and remove each independent subscribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `doOnSuccess`

```
postDetail = getPostDetail(postId).doOnSuccess { showPostDetails(it) }
getComments = getComments(postId).doOnSuccess { showComments(it) }
```

Then just merge them

```
Single.merge(postDetail, getComments)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe {
        showLoadingScreen()
    }
    .doOnTerminate {
        hideLoadingScreen()
    }
    .subscribe()
```